# How to do a code review for many commits in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

What is the easiest/best way to review a merge request in gitlab for a branch that has many commits?
Is there a “unified” view I can use somehow or is the only option to click on the “Changes” tab and go through each individual commits one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to go through each invidividual commit one by one.

You should click on the Merge Request's "Changes" tab, instead of the "Changes" tab of individual commits, so you see the changes between the latest version and the branch you want to merge into, e.g. with Master:

[image]

This way, you will see all changes that are proposed within the merge request and you can review them all at once.